# Convert Infix to Postfix with Binary Tree

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures

I'm trying to make an infix to postfix converter. I have already searched for code in Google but most of the algorithms were with stack or using lot's of regular expression or hard to understand, but I want to make this with Binary Tree.

here is what i have already did:

Class Node:

```
public class Node
{
    private object element;
    private Node left;
    private Node right;
    private Node parent;

    public Node()
    {
    }

    public Node(object x, Node r, Node l)
    {
        element = x;
        right = r;
        left = l;
    }

    public object GetElement()
    {
        return element;
    }

    public void SetElement(object x)
    {
        element = x;
    }

    public Node GetLeft()
    {
        return left;
    }

    public void SetLeft(Node l)
    {
        left = l;
    }

    public Node GetRight()
    {
        return right;
    }

    public void SetRight(Node r)
    {
        right = r;
    }

    public Node GetParent()
    {
        return parent;
    }

    public void SetParent(Node p)
    {
        parent = p;
    }
}
```

Sorry for using get/set instead of simple auto property.

and my BST class that has Insert, Postfix, Prefix and Infix method (i have also writen search, deletemin, etc but we don't need them for my question)

BST Class:

```
public class BinarySearchTree
{
    //Node r: root.
    public void Insert(Node r, Node p, object x)
    {
        if (r == null)
        {
            r = new Node(x, null, null);
            r.SetParent(p);
            if ((int)x < (int)p.GetElement())
                p.SetLeft(r);
            else if ((int)x > (int)p.GetElement())
                p.SetRight(r);
        }
        if ((int) x < (int) r.GetElement())
            Insert(r.GetLeft(), r, x);
        else if ((int) x > (int) r.GetElement())
            Insert(r.GetRight(), r, x);
    }

    public void PreOrder(Node p)
    {
        if (p != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetElement());
            PreOrder(p.GetLeft());
            PreOrder(p.GetRight());
        }
    }

    public void Inorder(Node p)
    {
        if (p != null)
        {
            Inorder(p.GetLeft());
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetElement());
            Inorder(p.GetRight());
        }
    }

    public void Postorder(Node p)
    {
        if (p != null)
        {
            Postorder(p.GetLeft());
            Postorder(p.GetRight());
            Console.WriteLine(p.GetElement());
        }
    }
}
```

My insert method is work for numbers for example:
If we want to write Inorder, Preorder and post order of below tree

[image]

Preorder: 5, 3, 2, 4, 7, 6, 12
Postorder: 2, 4, 3, 6, 12, 7, 5
Inorder: 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 12

Main method for this example:

```
private static void Main()
{
    BinarySearchTree bst = new BinarySearchTree();
    Node r = new Node(5, null, null);
    bst.Insert(r, null, 3);
    bst.Insert(r, null, 7);
    bst.Insert(r, null, 4);
    bst.Insert(r, null, 12);
    bst.Insert(r, null, 2);
    bst.Insert(r, null, 6);
    bst.Inorder(r);
    Console.WriteLine();
    bst.Postorder(r);
    Console.WriteLine();
    bst.PreOrder(r);
}
```

now I want to make a infix to postfix converter but don't know how to implement insert method for that, and how to handle operator and operands in order. and another problem is parentheses.
would be grateful if help me with some code.

An example with tree:

[image]

mathblog has a infix to postfix converter, you can check yours with it.
http://www.mathblog.dk/tools/infix-postfix-converter/

Comment: Why do you want to do it with a BST? Stack-based algorithm is rather simple and efficient at the same time.

Comment: it was an assignment that my teacher gave us, that we should have worked with BST. i'm confused in how to insert the tree. and anyway it is a good challenge for improvement in algorithm.

Comment: You want a binary tree, *not* a binary search tree. With a BST, the nodes are ordered by value. In the binary tree representation of an expression, the interior nodes are operators and the leaf nodes are operands (i.e. numbers in your case). See [Binary expression tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_expression_tree) for a detailed explanation, including a good example of how they're created.

Comment: @JimMischel the example in your link is for converting postfix to infix, but i want infix to postfix.can you write some of the code at least just for * +. i'll expand it if i got it.

Comment: @JimMischel I edited my question. (changed BST to binary tree.)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the easiest way to convert the expression from infix to postfix notation is to use a standard stack based algorithm(it has linear time complexity, so it is optimal) and then to build a tree(constructing a tree from postfix expression is simple because all operators are in a correct order).

Comment: @masoodm You can maintain roots for subexpressions on a stack and then combine them into a new root when an operation is applied. At the end you will have only one tree node on the stack: the root of the entire tree.